# Tomcat Cluster 6 and ContextListener

Tags: java, tomcat, replication, cluster-computing

On single instance of Tomcat I have a thread that was started when context was initialized. Something like this :

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
private MyThread thread = null;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    //Start thread...
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    //Stop thread...
}
}
```

This thread performs some important jobs in system every 10 minutes, and it was working  fine.

Now I have switched to cluster of to instances of tomcat and this thread is running on two instances. I'm trying to achieve different behavior.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- This thread should be running only on one instance at the time.
- If first instance fails (on which thread was running), thread should be started on second instance.

I would be grateful for any hint.

What is my application logic ?
Application logic that is executed by a thread is as follows:

1. Read sth from DB.
2. Analyze DB information.
3. Do HTTP request to external system, if needed.
4. Sleep thread for another 10 minutes.

The point is: If I will have 2 instances of tomcat, only one should execute this logic

Comment: I guess what you are actually doing is **purely an application logic** and I assume (as you don't mention) that you are not using any underlying infrastructural components (like sessions etc) managed by Tomcat itself to achieve what you are trying to do. Hence its least likely that clustering will inherently support this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't use sessions. Application logic that is executed by a thread is as follows: 1. Read sth from DB. 2. Analyze DB information. 3. Do HTTP request to external system, if needed. 4. Sleep thread for another 10 minutes. The point is: If I will have 2 instances of tomcat, only one should execute this logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are not really allowed to start a new thread in your application when using a web-application-server.  All threads must be managed by the application server.